# How to know when a UITableViewCell is done with its AutoLayout pass

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I supply a cell with some text and a URL for an image.
The ImageView that displays the image with an `imageFromURL:` method is a custom class that internally looks at its own size and appends a query to the URL, like:

```
.com/img.png?ver=200&hor=500
```

The server then figures out which size image to return to get the best result.

This means I need AutoLayout to layout the imageView before there is any content other than the text. After I am guaranteed that the imageView has its final size I call the `imageWithURL:` method.

The autolayout I constructed fill up my textLabel and since the cell height is fixed it then decides what is left for the image. (some compression resistance, minimum sizes etc go into this - this all works and I omitted it from the code below).

```
- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    /*
     stuff that goes into making the cell ready
     .
     .
     .
     */
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
    /*
     first set the different constraints
     .
     .
     .
     then call super
     */
     [super updateConstraints];
}

- (void) updateCellWithText:(NSString*) text andImageURL:(NSURL*) imgURL
{
    self.textLabel.text = text;
    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:imgURL];
    //calling setNeedsUpdateConstraints here won't help much as there is still not a correct size
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.imageView.frame.size));
}
```

What I log from `layoutSubviews:` is:

- {0,0} //first time around
- {320,498} //OK now it looks right - could call imageWithURL: now
- {320,498} //Probably one extra for calculating the cell or tableview
  height?

My goal is to figure out when we are done laying out and I can call my `setImageWithURL:` with a correct size for the imageView.
layoutSubviews seems to be the only place I can hook into this info - but I really feel uncomfortable in adding code like this to layoutSubviews and mixing my data update into my layout code:

```
if (_imageView.frame.size.width == 0)
    [_imageView setImageWithURL:_propertyWithURL];
```

Also from the above logging that would cause my image to be set 2 times as layoutSubviews is called multiple times.

So, hope someone can help me get the order of these calls right or suggest a different approach to achieve the result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. How did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to explicitly call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` in init. This *may* be causing the double layout calls. There is also a very good chance `layoutSubviews` will get called frequently, as this is the method that is called after `updateConstraints` in order to set the frames of each view in addition to any other actions that mark the layout as dirty. However, this would be the correct place to check for a frame that is the result of an auto-layout pass since that is what you are interested in.

There are a couple of ways you can handle this:

### Force Layout

If you *know* that your views constraints have already been installed and you want to force a layout pass *right now*, you could mark the view's layout as dirty and call `layoutIfNeeded`:

```
[self setNeedLayout];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
CGSize imageSize = self.imageView.bounds.size;
```

Use this method sparingly as it is basically forcing the system to layout when you tell it to. Normally, you want to allow the system to layout as needed since layout can be expensive with auto-layout.

### Only Update Image When Changed

Another approach would be to just let the system handle layout like normal while still checking the frame of the image view in `layoutSubviews`, but only fetch a new image if the size of the image is different than the one you have already set on it. This would give you the result you're looking for in this case since the size of the image view is the same in the second two passes. This also allows the image view to change sizes and still get an updated image:

```
if (CGSizeEqualToSize(self.imageView.bounds.size, self.lastImageViewSize) == NO) {
  //fetch new image from server
}
```

Also -- make sure you're requesting images at double resolution for retina displays. You can get the screen scale using the `scale` property on `UIScreen` And multiply each dimension by that to handle it generically. If you aren't building for multiple screens, just use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`

Answer (score 1):

First off, use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to detect when the view finishes laying out the subviews.

Secondly, sometimes even `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is automatically called multiple times. If you want to make sure you're only setting the image once, perhaps add a class variable, ex. `bool viewLaidout;`, initialize it to `NO` in `viewDidLoad`, only set the image in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` if `viewLaidout == NO`, then in the first pass of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, set the image and set `viewLaidout` to `YES`, ex:

```
bool viewLaidout;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    viewLaidout = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (viewLaidout == NO) {
        [_imageView setImageWithURL:_propertyWithURL];
        viewLaidout = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lyndsey. viewDidLayoutSubviews is a method on the (table)viewController. Would I have to construct some mapping of witch cells are visible and then update the URL's there?